Proof the following fact(commutative algebra)
Suppose $\varphi : R \to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. If $R$ is a semi-local ring, proof that $\varphi (rad(R)) = rad(S)$, where $rad(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$.
It is easy to proof that $\varphi (rad(R)) \subseteq rad(S)$, but I can not figure out how to proof the other side because the surjective homomorphism makes it hard to see what the preimage of $s \in S$ is like in the ring R, for example, $\varphi^{-1} (1_s)$ may contains more than one preimage in $R$.
I also tried to use the necessary and sufficient condition "$x \in rad(R) \Leftrightarrow 1+Rx \subseteq R^*$", but I still failed to deal with the problem because of the surjective homomorphism. I came to realize that I need to avoid the surjective homomorphism, but I don't know how.

Welcome to MSE! What have you tried on this problem?

in this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. This is not a homework service. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

@larruping I am voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of another question, linked below. Hopefully the answer to the linked question satisfies your needs.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010740/if-a-is-a-semilocal-ring-and-fa-rightarrow-b-is-a-surjective-homomorphism?noredirect=1&lq=1
